# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in hello world

Tags: objective-c

Today I'm learning Objective-C without Xcode following this [Guide](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html)

Here's the hello world:

**makclass.m**

```
#import "makclass.h"
#import <stdio.h>

@implementation MakClass

-(void) age {
    printf("Age is %d", age);
}

-(void) setAge: (int) a {
    age = a;
}

+(void) say {
    printf("Haha");
}
@end
```

**makclass.h**

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>
@interface MakClass: NSObject {
    int age;
}

-(void) age;
-(void) setAge: (int) a;
+(void) say;
@end
```

**helloworld.m**

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import "makclass.h"
int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World");
    MakClass *makclass = [[MakClass alloc] init];
    [makclass setAge: 1];
    [makclass age];
    [MakClass say];
    [makclass release];
    return 0;
}
```

And `clang helloworld.m` give me the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MakClass", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in helloworld-XEijke.o
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      _main in helloworld-XEijke.o
  "_objc_msgSend_fixup", referenced from:
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc in helloworld-XEijke.o
      l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release in helloworld-XEijke.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you pass in the framework and all the files as well:

`clang -framework Foundation -o helloworld helloworld.m makclass.m`

Comment: You also need both `helloworld.m` and `makclass.m` on the command line: `clang -framework Foundation helloworld.m makclass.m`

Comment: Edited with that stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Objective-C!

When you compile, you need to specify all of the implementation files that `helloworld.m` requires.  Just because the header files are included does not mean that the implementation files will be included as well.

Additionally, since this is Objective-C, make sure you also include the `-lObjC` flag to include the Objective-C libraries.

So, the command that you should run will look like `clang -lObjC helloworld.m makclass.m`.

`clang` will then spit out a program called `a.out`, which you can run.  If you want to change the name from `a.out` to, say, `helloworld`, you can specify that with the `-o` flag.  For example:

```
clang -lObjc -o helloworld helloworld.m makclass.m
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your warm welcome! your solution works, but I can't use NSLog() function, so I think @Wevah's answer is better.